# Advantages of define over let

Tags: racket, let

During a conversation with [Matt Flatt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matthew_Flatt), one of the primary authors of Racket, I was told (in passing) that the `let` form is not recommended by the community and is largely being replaced by `define`.

What are the advantages of `define` over `let` that would prompt the Racket community to elect to use it in place of `let`?

For reference, [define](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/define.html) and [let](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/let.html) from the Racket documentation are linked here.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

"To reduce rightward drift"

See the section 4.2 on definitions:
https://docs.racket-lang.org/style/Choosing_the_Right_Construct.html

That said, I see it mostly as a matter of taste.

Comment: Internal definitions also allows you to easily intertwine definitions with the rest of the code, if you like this style.

Comment: Oh, and `let` also allows you to control the scope of bindings more easily than `define`.