# Why is let preferred to define in Scheme?

Tags: coding-style, scheme, let

I've always written my Scheme procedures (and seen them written) like this:

```
(define (foo x)
  (let ((a ...))
       ((b ...))
    ...))
```

One of my students wrote:

```
(define (foo x)
  (define a ...)
  (define b ...)
  ...)
```

Both give the same results. I understand the difference in behavior: The first creates a new frame that points to the procedure application frame, while the latter modifies the procedure application frame directly. The latter would yield slightly better performance.

Another difference is that the former avoids using the implicit `begin` before a sequence of instructions in a procedure body.

Why is the former standard style?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not completely equivalent. `define` within a procedure body is more like a `letrec` so you might get surprised you cannot use the value bound in a `define` before all of them are finished and the body of the procedure is to be executed. Imagine you want to do do x + y * z:

```
(define (test x y z)
  (let ((ytimesz (* y z)))
     (let ((sum (+ x ytimesz)))
       (dosomething sum))))
```

The reason you have a nested let here is because `ytimesz` can't be accessed in the same let as it is made. We have another special form for that `let*`

```
(define (test x y z)
  (let* ((ytimesz (* y z)) (sum (+ x ytimesz)))
       (dosomething sum)))
```

`letrec` and `letrec*` are similar but allows for recursion so in a lambda you can call one of the other bound member or itself. Now, depending on the version of Scheme you are using, you will get one of these when writing:

```
(define (test x y z)
  (define ytimesz (* y z))
  (define answer (+ x ytimesz)) ;might work, might not
  (dosomething answer))
```

In `#!R7RS`, `#!R6RS` and `#!Racket` it's perfectly ok since this are defined as `letrec*`.

In `#!R5RS`, however, it won't work at all. The rewrite is done as `letrec` and it initializes all variables (`ytimesz` and `answer`) to an undefined value, then assignes the evaluation of the expressions to temporary variables before `set!`-ing the variables to the values of the temporary values to make sure all use of any of them ends up as undefined values and some even signal errors (Racket does in R5RS-mode. For lambda-expressions where the bindings in the body are evaluated at call time, this is no problem and it's for these `letrec` and internal `define` is originally meant for.

I use `define` to store simple values and procedures. The second I think I need to use a precalculated value I might rewrite the whole thing to a `let*` or combine `define` and a simple `let`.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Do you know why define in a procedure behaves differently from at the top-level?

Comment: R6RS internal definitions, like R7RS ones, use `letrec*`, not `letrec`.

Comment: @espertus Because the Scheme language defined two different meanings to `define`, one for top-level bindings and one for, essentially, syntactic sugar for `letrec*`. That's Scheme for you. :-)

Comment: @ChrisJester-Young fixed R6RS. Top level difference must be because top level in reality isn't a frame or just one frame. A top level define alters "top frame" but is evaluated later then previous `define` making it special?

Answer (score 6):

Actually, both styles are fine. [In fact, some people prefer to use internal definitions.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21651962/13)

Also, the latter doesn't necessarily "modify the procedure application frame directly", either; internal definitions are treated the same as a `letrec` (for R5RS-compliant systems) or `letrec*` (for R6RS- and R7RS-compliant systems). Thus, your second example is really the same as:

```
(define (foo x)
  (letrec* ((a ...)
            (b ...))
    ...))
```

In fact, to use an example, Racket rewrites internal definitions to their equivalent `letrec*` expressions and there is thus no difference in performance (beyond whatever difference there is between `let` and `letrec*`, of course).

Comment: Thanks for correcting my misunderstanding. We are indeed using Racket.

Comment: Thanks too for the link on style.